# installing spark 1.4.1 in CDH 5.4.2

Tags: apache-spark, installation, cloudera

I am very new to spark and I want to install latest version of spark on my VM. Can anyone please guide me on how to install spark 1.4.1 on my cloudera VM version 5.4.2. I have currently spark 1.3.0 installed (Default that comes already installed in CDH 5.4.2) on my cloudera.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Officially you will need to wait for Cloudera to release (and support) the newer version of Spark with CDH.

If you need a newer version of Spark before then you can download Spark yourself and install it alongside CDH.

http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

You can still use the other CDH Hadoop systems (e.g. HDFS, Hive, etc) from a separate Spark installation.